# Choosing which speaker to output audio

Tags: audio, html5-audio, mediadevices

Let's say you are building a web app and it will run on a mobile device with two speakers, loudspeaker and the phone speaker you hold on your ear while on a call.

Can one select the speaker to output the audio with HTML5 and JavaScript?
We do this when on a phone call to put the call in loudspeaker or vice versa.

I have checked MDN documentation about Audio elements and MediaDevices API but could not see anything about the audio output devices in general, it is usually all about input devices.

Comment: Perhaps on chrome as an experimental feature? https://jsfiddle.net/2k7gkdqw/1/ still an open issue https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api-v2/issues/10

Comment: Thanks. Is your point using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`? In MDN page it say this method returns an array of input and output devices. But in FF I get only the video and audio input devices, whereas on same device I get 3 audio input, 3 audio output, 1 video input devices. Strange.

Comment: @fdcp Aldo my version of the fiddle to enumerate media devices: https://jsfiddle.net/fselcukcan/ybk2c5u7/
Your did not worked fro me since there were legacy code about Media Devices feature.
On Adnroid Chrome it shows only 1 audio output.

Comment: Apologies, should have been clearer. That fiddle is linked to in the issue. It is from 2016 so I imagine things have progressed. It is a non-standard feature so do not expect consistent behaviour across web browsers

Comment: That doc specifies sinkId and setSinkId. Currently Chrome has it on `audio` element, and on `AudioContext`.
https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-output/#h-webaudio-extensions

Comment: I guess `MediaDevices.selectAudioOutput()` is on its way. Though not quite supported yet by the majority of the browsers.

Comment: Hi @sçuçu . I am running into the same issue. So I guess selecting the output speaker in a web app is not possible yet?

Comment: Hi @justadeveloper, I wish I was active on the subject but as far as I can see from https://caniuse.com/?search=selectAudioOutput and related MDN page support tables this method not supported yet at all, as of today, except in firefox it is behind a flag. But I have not tried it. I guess it is not possible yet.